# merging arrays from n file into a new file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, array-merge

I have three files each containing columns that are a mixture of ints and floats for example the first line from each of the files is:

```
file1

1.0000,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0,0,0,8.7129,-102.3384,142.2611,0
```

```
file2
1640 3110 1780
```

```
file3
12.97 10 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 2959.933838 1829.955933 945.020020 240 90 -285 0.419335 0.726310 0.544639 0.272320 0.471671 -0.838671 -0.866025 0.500000 0.000000 1
```

I now want create a new file that merges specific fields from each of the three fields, to that end I have written the following program

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rfn

tbl1 = np.genfromtxt('file1', delimiter=",", dtype=None,\
                     names=['CCC','reserved','reserved','pIndex','wedgeWt',\
                            'NA','NA','NA','NA','NA',\
                            'xOffset','yOffset','zOffset',\
                            'NA','NA','reserved',\
                            'phi','psi','theta','reserved'])
tbl2 = np.genfromtxt('file2', delimiter=" ", dtype=None, names=['x','y','z'])
tbl3 = np.genfromtxt('file3', delimiter=" ",\
                     names=['CCC','Bin','NA','pIDX','NA','NA','NA','NA','NA','NA',\
                            'X','Y','Z','phi','theta','psi',\
                            'r11','r21','r31','r12','r22','r32','r13','r23','r33','classIDx'])
tbl_out=rfn.merge_arrays([tbl1['CCC'],\
                         [tbl3['Bin'],['NA']],\
                         [tbl1['pIndex']],\
                         [tbl3['NA'],['NA'],['NA'],['NA'],['NA'],['NA']],\
                         [tbl2['x'],['y'],['z']],\
                         [tbl1['phi'],['theta'],['psi']],\
                         [tbl3['r11'],['r21'],['r31'],['r12'],['r22'],['r32'],['r13'],['r23'],['r33'],['classIDx']])
np.savetxt('outfile.csv',tbl_out,delimiter=" ")
```

After saving, the outfile.csv contains only one value. I would really appreciate some conceptual clarification on what is going wrong with my code.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: First, does `tbl_out` look right?  What value do you see in the `csv` file?  Any relation to the array?  What's the `shape` and `dtype` of `tbl_out`?

Comment: No, it holds only one value the first value (CCC) in the row. The shape is 1,1 and dtype is a float

Comment: You can't write a correct `csv` if the merged array isn't right to start with.  Have you tried a simpler merge?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I was able to solve this, the problem was with the way the square brackets were positioned. The right way to write the code was

```
tbl_out=rfn.merge_arrays([tbl1[['CCC']],tbl3[['Bin','NA8']],\
                         tbl1[['pIndex']],\
                         tbl3[['NA9','NA10','NA11','NA12','NA13','NA14']],\
                         tbl2[['x','y','z']],\
                         tbl1[['phi','theta','psi']],\
                         tbl3[['r11','r21','r31','r12','r22','r32','r13','r23','r33']],\
                         tbl3[['classIDx']]], flatten=True, usemask=False)
```